# Ignore ambiguous layout warning in IB

Tags: ios, interface-builder, ios7, autolayout

I have a view defined in Interface Builder whose autolayout constraints can be defined in IB, except for one. This one I added by code in `viewDidLoad`.

This is all good and dandy except that IB shows the ambiguous layout warning, because it's not aware of the extra constraint I added by code.

Is there a way to tell IB to ignore this warning? Or should I be doing something differently?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way to tell IB to ignore this warning?

No, as far as I know there's no way of ignoring a warning in IB.

One strategy could be to add a placeholder constraint in IB with the only purpose of shutting the warning down, and select the `Remove at build time`  option of such constraint from the inspector.

Interface builder won't show the warning and the constraint won't be there at runtime.

Comment: As mentioned in the question, I cannot express all the constraints in IB. The one I can't, I added by code. The others, I want to define in IB to avoid writing code. So my layout IS deterministic, I just can't use IB to define it fully.

Comment: It doesn't matter where you defined them. You haven't added enough constraints to determine the layout. If you are more specific and post the error message it's easier to help.

Comment: I'm most likely not explaining myself very well. Let's try again. I certainly haven't added enough constraints to determine the layout, IN IB. That's because I can't. There's one constraint that I need to add by code. Which I did. So there's no ambiguous layout at runtime. I would like to use IB to define as many constraints as I can, and use code for the rest. However, I would also like to indicate IB that what it thinks is an ambiguous layout is actually handled by the file's owner, if possible. Or do things differently, if it's not possible.

Comment: Oh ok, I'm sorry I didn't catch the part where the warning is only presented in IB.